# Looping in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a loop in JQuery to show data !
I am consuming data from an API . 
Seems that I am getting a syntax error .

Can I do it this way ?

```
$.each(data.results, function (i, item) { // on this line

    var Name = item.name;
    var Date = item.auditInfo.dateCreated;
    var Creator = item.creator.display;
    $htmlstring.append($('<li/>').append('<p>Test</p>'));
    $htmlstring.append("<div class='title'> Info : "
    Name + Date + Creator "</div>");

});
$('#afficher').html($htmlstring);
```

Comment: are you receiving an error message? does it work? does it not work?

Comment: Yup , it doesn't work out !

Comment: What is the error message ? the var Date is definitely  a problem.

Comment: have you tried debugging it? what's in the data.result variable?

Comment: Maybe add some `+ " " +` between the Name+Date+Creator

Comment: I ve changed the date var ; it's not the prob !

Comment: @Epsilon_G: Add more info. What is the value of `data`? What is the *exact* error that you're getting? Without that, this question is unanswerable.

Comment: What type of element is `data.results`?

Comment: You seem to be missing a `+` between the string literal and `Date` and after `Creator`.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to pass a set of DOM elements (`$htmlstring`) to a function that expects an HTML string (`.html`).

Try using `$('#afficher').append($htmlstring)` instead.  [Oh, and rename your variable, since it's not an HTML string!]

You're also trying to construct illegal HTML.  Assuming that the initial container element of `$htmlstring` is a `<ul>` (since you're adding `<li>` items) you can't add `<p>` or `<div>` items to a `<ul>`.

Assuming that those elements are supposed to be *within* the `<li>` element:

```
var container = $('<ul>');

$.each(data.results, function (i, item) {

    var name = item.name;
    var date = item.auditInfo.dateCreated;
    var creator = item.creator.display;

    var li = $('<li>').appendTo(container);
    li.append('<p>Test</p>');
    li.append($('<div>', {
        'class': 'title',
        'text' : 'Info : ' + name + date + creator
    }));

});

$('#afficher').append(container);
```

Comment: I didn't find what did you change with "$('#afficher').html($htmlstring);" .

Comment: `.html()` does accept jQuery objects.

Comment: @Blender not according to the API docs